# Android multi thread application - sharing state

Tags: android, multithreading, gps

I am working on Android application that has several threads - one of them is getting data from GPS receiver 1 time per second. I would like other threads to have access to information from the GPS thread.

I already tried doing it with message queues, but it made the code quite messy - all new threads I created had to handle messages in it's own way, so I had to do a lot of new implementation in every thread class.

I would like to be able to simply get the data in this manner:

```
ApplicationState.getLocation();
```

so I can use the most recent data. How can I accomplish it? I don't want to create static class with synchronized fields because I don't want to lock the threads for too long because I am doing some online image analysis in other thread.

What approach would be the best here?

Cheers,
Nebril

Comment: You might want to look into the `volatile` keyword for your coordinate variables as you seem to only need 3 `double`s for `(x, y, z)`: [little howto](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml)

Comment: I would like to have some generic way of sharing different variables. Also, quoting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable#In_Java "(However, there is no guarantee about the relative ordering of volatile reads and writes with regular reads and writes, meaning that it's generally not a useful threading construct.)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using an Event Bus system? [Otto, an Apache licensed library from Square](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/07/otto.html) is pretty neat.

You could create a location updating class that fires new `LocationUpdateEvents`. Any objects interested in receiving this update can have a method annotated with `@Subscribe`. It's sweet method for interprocess communication that doesn't rely on messy listener interfaces.

Another advantage of Otto is that your LocationUpdater class could have a method annotated with @Produce. With this, any object that `begins` listening for `LocationUpdateEvents` will receive one immediately with the last location found by your `LocationUpdater`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just before reading your answer me and my colleagues decided to implement Observer pattern, which is quite similar to Event Bus. If we get too tired of coding we will give Otto a try :)

Comment: Otto is not intended for interprocess communication !!! See https://github.com/square/otto/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/squareup/otto/Bus.java  But in your case (you use multi-thread and not milti-process app) otto will be a good choice of dev.

Answer (score 1):

1)create your application class "MyApp" :

1.1)in the manifest file:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    ....
/>
```

1.2)create the class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
    }

    private volatile Location mLastLocation = null;
    public Location getLastLocation(){
        return mLastLocation;
    }
    public void setLastLocation(Location mLastLocation){
        this.mLastLocation = mLastLocation;
    }
}
```

2)to set the location from any context in your application (services, any activities) in the same process (be careful to have one process. You can have 1 process and multi thread in android) :

```
((MyApp)context.getApplicationContext()).setLastLocation(location);
```

3)to get the latest location from any context in your application in the same process:

```
((MyApp)context.getApplicationContext()).getLastLocation();
```

NB: you can also use listeners for better performance. Register in a list in MyApp listeners and trigger the listeners from onLocationChanged

Comment: Is it ok to pass context to every single thread in application? I mean, is context object thread safe?

Comment: application context is already shared by all others (services and activities). Just be careful to have just one process.